# jQuery select all link but exclude the link inside an iframe

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have many links inside the the body, and many links inside an iframe, something likes:

```
<div>
<a herf=xxxxxxx>...</a>
<a herf=xxxxxxx>...</a>
<a herf=xxxxxxx>...</a>
...
<a herf=xxxxxxx>...</a>
</div>
<iframe src=xxx>
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
<a herf=xxxxxxx>...</a>
<a herf=xxxxxxx>...</a>
<a herf=xxxxxxx>...</a>
...
<a herf=xxxxxxx>...</a>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

How can jQuery to select all link but exclude the link inside an iframe?

Thanks

Comment: Does jQuery select elements inside `<iframe>`s by default? I didn't think it did...

Comment: Show js fiddle where this happens. I don't believe it would select the links from the iframes with selector like `$('a')`.

Comment: @qwzjk is right, you cannot actually access elements inside an iframe without using specific code to explicitly access iframe's contents. (see http://api.jquery.com/contents/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if `$('a')` selects links from iframe too, I think it selects only from current document.

You can add a `class="acls"` in each `<a>` you want to select, then in jQuery use: `$('a.acls')` .

Comment: Yes, the a tag inside iframe will not be selected by `$('a')`, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get links only from div, not from iframe, you can use:

```
var links = $("div a");
```

If you want to parse URLs from links, try something like that:

```
var urls = [];
$("div a").each(function() { 
    urls.push($(this).attr('href'));

});
```

I hope it wiil help